# Mysql Concatenate Left Join to more than one Column?

Tags: mysql, concatenation, left-join

I've got a MySQL Select statement which concatenates tags in a left join.

```
LEFT JOIN tags t on t.tagid = et.tagid1
```

But I need to join the tags to three other columns.

I tried;

```
  LEFT JOIN tags t on t.tagid = et.tagid1, et.tagid2, et.tagid3
```

But I got an error.

Is there a way to do this? Here's the full select statement;

```
SELECT ap.userid,     
        (
            SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t.tagname)
            FROM entitytag et
            LEFT JOIN tags t on t.tagid = et.tagid1     
            WHERE et.audioid = ap.audioid
        ) tagname,
            FROM audioposts ap 
            LEFT JOIN accounts ac ON ac.id = ap.userid
          WHERE ap.opid = '0'
```

Comment: please show us your error.

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `on` clause has to have an expression that determines whether a given pair of rows should be joined; here you want to join t rows that have a tagid that is one of tagid1, tagid2, or tagid3, so you need (after the `ON`):

```
t.tagid = et.tagid1 or t.tagid = et.tagid2 or t.tagid = et.tagid3
```

or the equivalent using the IN operator:

```
t.tagId in (et.tagid1, et.tagid2, et.tagid3)
```

Comment: Actually I misread your code. This works; LEFT JOIN tags t on t.tagid in (et.tagid1, et.tagid2, et.tagid3)

Comment: Can you edit it in and I'll select it?

Comment: part of my whole point was there isn't some magical meaning to `left join .. on .. =`; what comes after the on can be *any* expression